# Pyspark Row() in columns cells to a full dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, row, explode

I have 1 big df now with Row() in the column 'dataframe'

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+---+--------------------+----------+
|           file_name|            log_time|line_num|ind|           dataframe|      date|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+---+--------------------+----------+
|service.log-20200...|2020-05-08 04:00:...|     216|101|[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...|2020-05-08|
|service.log-20200...|2020-05-08 04:01:...|     773|101|[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...|2020-05-08|
|service.log-20200...|2020-05-08 04:03:...|    1300|101|[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...|2020-05-08|
|service.log-20200...|2020-05-08 04:04:...|    2028|101|[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...|2020-05-08|
|service.log-20200...|2020-05-08 04:05:...|    2267|101|[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...|2020-05-08|
|service.log-20200...|2020-05-08 04:06:...|    2816|101|[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...|2020-05-08|
|service.log-20200...|2020-05-08 04:08:...|    3353|101|[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...|2020-05-08|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+---+--------------------+----------+

df.select('dataframe').take(1)
>>>[Row(dataframe=[Row(column1=0.0, column2=0.0, column3=0.0, column4=0.0,...

df.PrintSchema()
>>>root
>>> |-- file_name: string (nullable = true)
>>> |-- log_time: string (nullable = true)
>>> |-- line_num: long (nullable = true)
>>> |-- ind: string (nullable = true)
>>> |-- dataframe: array (nullable = true)
>>> |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
>>> |    |    |-- column1: double (nullable = true)
>>> |    |    |-- column2: double (nullable = true)
>>> |    |    |-- column3: double (nullable = true)
>>> |    |    |-- column4: double (nullable = true)
>>>...
```

How can I combine all these rows in separate df or "explode" these rows in the original df?
the expected output is something like this:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+---+--------+-------+---+---------+----------+
|           file_name|            log_time|line_num|ind| column1|column2|...|column380|      date|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+---+--------+-------+---+---------+----------+
|service.log-20200...|2020-05-08 04:00:...|     216|101|     0.0|    0.0|...|      0.0|2020-05-08|
|service.log-20200...|2020-05-08 04:00:...|     773|101|     0.0|    0.0|...|      0.0|2020-05-08|
|service.log-20200...|2020-05-08 04:00:...|    1300|101|     0.0|    0.0|...|      0.0|2020-05-08|
|service.log-20200...|2020-05-08 04:00:...|    2028|101|     0.0|    0.0|...|      0.0|2020-05-08|
|service.log-20200...|2020-05-08 04:00:...|    2267|101|     0.0|    0.0|...|      0.0|2020-05-08|
```

Comment: Nope. that was also my question, but here its is simplified, because I exploded those DFs into the main DF.

Comment: Please add your expected output to the question!

Comment: ok, I've added the expected result

Answer (score 0):

You may use toDF() function :

```
data = df.select('dataframe')
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
df=rdd.toDF()
```

You can also specify new df column names:

```
names = ["A","B","C"]
df=rdd.toDF(*names)
```